# Sorting data in a stored array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Below is my code. I need to sort the array after the user input but can't figure out how to make that happen. I have tried several different things but nothing has worked including data.sort() and data.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b; }); but neither seems to be working. Any help would be appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Input integers into the array and then search the array to see if your input is present!</h1>
  <p id="data">[]</p>
  <input id="inputNumber" value="0" /> <button id="pushBtn" onclick="push()">PUSH</button>
  <input id="findNumber" value="0" /> <button id="pushBtn" onclick="find()">FIND</button>
  <script>
    var data = [];


    function push(e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        data.push(prompt('enter integer ' + (i + 1)));
      }
      alert('Full array: ' + data.join(', '));
      var toAdd = document.getElementById("inputNumber").value;
      data.push(toAdd);
      refresh();


    }

    function find(e) {
      var toFind = document.getElementById("findNumber").value;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] == toFind) return alert("found at " + i);
      }
      return alert("That number was not found");
    }

    function refresh() {
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If this is anything other than an exercise, I'd rethink the experience of five browser prompts in succession.

Comment: Adding `data.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b });` immediately after your `for` loop in the `push()` function *does* sort the array. I just tried that with your code, changing nothing else, and it worked. (Assuming the user actually entered numbers.)

Comment: yeah, good point. It is just an exercise but that was the only way I could figure out how to do it because I am a coding newbie